# Fire UILocalNotification Weekly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification, nscalendar

I can't seem to figure out why this notification is not scheduling on Saturdays... I've tried both `NSGregorianCalendar` and `autoupdatingCurrentCalendar`. I'm setting `[dateComps setWeekday:7];`, but it keeps returning Sundays.

```
//NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
 NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *timeComponent = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) fromDate:reminderTime];
 // Set up the fire time
 NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
 [dateComps setYear: 2012];;
 [dateComps setHour: timeComponent.hour];
 [dateComps setMinute: timeComponent.minute];
 [dateComps setSecond:0];
 // Set day of the week
 [dateComps setWeekday:7];
 NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];

 UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
 if (notification == nil)
     return;
 notification.fireDate = itemDate;
 notification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dateComps` as you calculate it, does not contain a day or month so that `setWeekday` is just ignored and `itemDate` is a date on the first January 2012 (which was a Sunday).

To compute the next Saturday, you can proceed as described in [Adding Components to a Date](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html) of the "Date and Time Programming Guide":

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

// Weekday of "reminderTime":
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:reminderTime];

// Number of weekdays until next Saturday:
NSDateComponents *componentsToAdd = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[componentsToAdd setDay: 7 - [weekdayComponents weekday]];

NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:componentsToAdd toDate:reminderTime options:0];
```